# Scala - dynamically choose function

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm trying to dynamically choose a function, as follows:

```
val yld: (Nothing => Object) = {
          column.getType match {
            case PrimitiveType.PrimitiveTypeName.BINARY => new String(creader.getBinary.getBytes)
            case PrimitiveType.PrimitiveTypeName.BOOLEAN => creader.getBoolean
            case PrimitiveType.PrimitiveTypeName.DOUBLE => creader.getDouble
            case PrimitiveType.PrimitiveTypeName.FLOAT => creader.getFloat
            case PrimitiveType.PrimitiveTypeName.INT32 => creader.getInteger
            case PrimitiveType.PrimitiveTypeName.INT64 => creader.getLong
            case PrimitiveType.PrimitiveTypeName.INT96 => new String(creader.getBinary.getBytes)
            case PrimitiveType.PrimitiveTypeName.FIXED_LEN_BYTE_ARRAY => new String(creader.getBinary.getBytes)
          }
        }
```

**Question**: However, the inner functions (e.g. creader.getBoolean, etc.) are (obviously) executed at the time of the match. How do I capture those functions as objects to execute at a later time rather than having them execute when yld is assigned?

**Context:**

This is so that in a later `for` loop, I don't have to match again:

```
for (i <- 0L to 900000) {
    println(yld)
}
```

Because my object `creader` is an iterator on column-stored data, being able to make the type decision only one time should be more efficient than having to make it every time, i.e.

```
for (i <- 0L to 900000) {      
     column.getType match {
        case PrimitiveType.PrimitiveTypeName.BINARY => println(new String(creader.getBinary.getBytes))
        case PrimitiveType.PrimitiveTypeName.BOOLEAN => println(creader.getBoolean)
        case PrimitiveType.PrimitiveTypeName.DOUBLE => println(creader.getDouble)
        case PrimitiveType.PrimitiveTypeName.FLOAT => println(creader.getFloat)
        case PrimitiveType.PrimitiveTypeName.INT32 => println(creader.getInteger)
        case PrimitiveType.PrimitiveTypeName.INT64 => println(creader.getLong)
        case PrimitiveType.PrimitiveTypeName.INT96 => println(new String(creader.getBinary.getBytes))
        case PrimitiveType.PrimitiveTypeName.FIXED_LEN_BYTE_ARRAY => println(new String(creader.getBinary.getBytes))
      }          
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Ah, thank you! It seems I totally forgot to put an actual question in there. :)

Comment: I've edited to make the post clearer.

Comment: Cool, but you can still improve your question by simplifying it and making it self-contained; this `PrimitiveType.PrimitiveTypeName` enum seems like unnecessary complexity to explain the problem you're facing.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I will make sure to do that on future posts. I've gotten feedback on other posts that I don't provide enough context; it appears I went too far in the other direction on this one. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a method `def foo = 42` you can convert it to a function and assign it to a val by `val func = foo _`.